# In Algorithms I in cousera ,which terminal command line does the teacher use?

Tags: java, cmd, ide, git-bash

it's a good doc for people who first use java
but meet about command line i have a few questions
https://lift.cs.princeton.edu/java/windows/

His terminal code like this:

```
~/Desktop/hello> ls
Barnsley.java  COS 126.iml    WELCOME.txt    logo.png
~/Desktop/hello> javac-introcs Barnsley.java
~/Desktop/hello> java-introcs Barnsley 10000
```

but in my idea,it uses cmd.exe so `ls` should be replaced `dir` i know
but when i type `javac-introcs Barnsley.java`
it tells me

```
'java-introcs' is not an internal or external command, nor is it a runnable program
Or a batch file.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5FDX.png)

Comment: `java-introcs` is clearly something the instructor wrote (could be an alias) -- it is not a Java command. Intro cs (introduction to cs?) must add the various parameters. I suspect that just `javac` and `java` would be sufficient, though whether the instructor's commands added a classpath or something cannot be readily determined.

Comment: the prompt (`~/Desktop/hello>`) isn't a typical `cmd` prompt, so your idea might be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for you kind people to answer question,now i know that it is a custom made idea use Xming to use X windows system,so it is not cmd,and in the settings it says "bash“ . now I am so confused that Princeton University teacher is so cool

Answer (score 1):

The output you observed means that you haven't completed the installation of some class-specific programs. The installer for this is mentioned in Section 0 of [the link you provided](https://lift.cs.princeton.edu/java/windows/). The most likely cause is that there were some environmental variables that were not modified correctly to add the `java-introcs` executable or alias to `%PATH%`. However, you are probably able to replicate the intent of `java-introcs`, as described below.

To figure out how to make the given `Barnsley` file compile and run, you'll need to add the dependency `StdDraw.class` to the classpath when running the file. To do this, you can use the `java` and `javac` option `-classpath` or `-cp`. You can read more detailed documentation on how to do this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I download the version course provide,and it's linux version terminal. But the answer is very helpful for me to figure out how to make it in windows.TY again.

Comment: If this is for a specific course, I would ask your instructor for the aforementioned `StdDraw` class/java file. It may be that it is actually inside a `.jar` file, which is then what you would need to add to your command. Your command to compile would end up looking something like this: `javac -classpath ".:/path/to/StdDraw/" Barsley.java`, and you would include the same `-classpath [...]` parameter for `java` to run it.